# UIBarButton click to set flag value using Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift3, uibarbuttonitem

My scenario, I am having Two `UIBarButton` with action `method`, Here, whenever I am clicking `Done` and `Cancel` button I am moving to another `ViewController`. Once user clicked the Done `barbutton` I need to set some flag value and validate it another ViewController for `button` clicked or not clicked.

My ViewController One

```
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "backImgs"),
                                            style: .plain,
                                            target: self,
                                            action: #selector(menuButtonTapped))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem

@objc fileprivate func menuButtonTapped() { // here I need to set flag value }
```

My ViewController Two

```
class ViewControllertwo: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Here need to validate flag values to button clicked or not 
    }
}
```

Comment: actually what are the places you called `ViewControllertwo`

Comment: add some additional code, I mean `// here I need to set flag value` relevant push code

Comment: are you used the same target for both barbuttons

Comment: When creating the buttons, set their `tag` property. Afterwards, in the `menuButtonTapped`, check if the tag matches, then execute the code you need.

Answer (score 1):

I partially understand your question , in here you need to go with `tag` concept, for e.g

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "backImgs"),
                                        style: .plain,
                                        target: self,
                                        action: #selector(menuButtonTapped(_:)))
    barButtonItem.tag = 20
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(menuButtonTapped(_:)))
    cancelButton.tag = 10
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton
   }
```

handle your target function is like

```
  @objc fileprivate func menuButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  // if you dont want the tag concept, use title property for check which button tapped  //print("get Tapped button title  == \(sender.title)")
    //if sender.tag == 20{
        // clicked for another VC button, add your segue code here
   // }else{
        // pressed cancel button
   // }
     let vcTwo = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllertwo") as! ViewControllertwo
    vcTwo.getSelectedTag = sender.tag
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcTwo, animated: true)

}
```

on your VC2 create the one global Int for get the tag where its comes from,

** ViewControllertwo**

```
class ViewControllertwo : UIViewController {

    var getSelectedTag   = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if getSelectedTag == 20 {
            //pressed menu Tapped
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**As I understand your question the solution is -**

**ViewContorllerOne**

```
class ViewControllerOne : UIViewController {

    var isMenubuttonTapped : Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.actionToPushOnViewControllerTwo()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(actioFire), name: NSNotification.Name.init("MenuButtonTapped"), object: nil)
    }

    //Call from any where in viewControllerOne
    func actionToPushOnViewControllerTwo() {
        let viewControllerTwo : ViewControllerTwo = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerTwo") as! ViewControllerTwo
        self.present(viewControllerTwo, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func actioFire(_ notification: Notification) {
        print(notification.userInfo!["isMenuButtonTapped"] as Any)

        if let isMenuButtonTapped = notification.userInfo!["isMenuButtonTapped"] as? Bool {
            self.isMenubuttonTapped = isMenuButtonTapped
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewControllerTwo**

```
class ViewControllerTwo : UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "backImgs"),
                                                style: .plain,
                                                target: self,
                                                action: #selector(menuButtonTapped))
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
        }

        @objc fileprivate func menuButtonTapped() {
            // here I need to set flag value

            self.dismiss(animated: true) {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("MenuButtonTapped"),
                                                object: nil,
                                                userInfo:["isMenuButtonTapped": true])
            }
        }
    }
```

**Another Easy Solution is**

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            if let tabController = self.presentingViewController as? UITabBarController {
                if let navController = tabController.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController {
                    if let secondTab = navController.viewControllers.first as? HomeViewController {
                        secondTab.tfData = "YES"
                    }
                } else {
                    if let secondTab = tabController.selectedViewController as? HomeViewController {
                        secondTab.tfData = "YES"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. I will check and update you here @Nilesh R Patel

Comment: Hi Could you please tell me how to pass isMenubuttonTapped for dismiss view controller? @Nilesh R Patel

Comment: @devmikle Can you please tell what is the flow? because of little bit confusion
If you are push or present viewControllerTwo than you can pass isMenubuttonTapped fag using 

`let viewControllerTwo : ViewControllerTwo = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerTwo") as! ViewControllerTwo
        viewControllerTwo.isMenubuttonTapped = self.isMenuButtonTapped
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerTwo, animated: true)`

Comment: I am having two view controller. VC_one and Popup present. Here If we click VC_one tableview cell I am showing Popup by present model vc (not push nav). Now if I am click the Popup present bar button it will dismiss and show VC_one. when dismiss happen I need to pass some values to VC_one. FYI:VC_one, I am maintainting tabbar. @Nilesh R Patel

Comment: Superw. is it possible to pass some more values? @Nilesh R Patel

Comment: @devmikle yes its possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188726/discussion-between-devmikle-and-nilesh-r-patel).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your question, but assuming you are presenting ViewControllerOne from ViewControllerTwo, you're going to want to use the delegate pattern for this. This is similar to the way you use table/collection views, and you are essentially telling ViewControllerTwo to be ViewControllerOne's delegate so that it can react to the buttons being pressed.

Start by creating a protocol that defines the messages that ViewControllerOne can send to its delegate:

```
protocol ViewControllerOneDelegate: AnyObject {
  func viewControllerOneDidTapDone(_ viewController: ViewControllerOne)
  func viewControllerOneDidTapCancel(_ viewController: ViewControllerOne)
}
```

Then extend ViewControllerTwo to implement your protocol:

```
extension ViewControllerTwo: ViewControllerOneDelegate {
  func viewControllerOneDidTapDone(_ viewController: ViewControllerOne) {
    // Set your flag or do whatever you need to do on 'Done'.
    // Then dismiss viewController.
  }
  func viewControllerOneDidTapCancel(_ viewController: ViewControllerOne) {
    // Dismiss viewController
  }
}
```

In ViewControllerOne, keep the delegate as a weak property and call the delegate methods on button press:

```
class ViewControllerOne: UIViewController {
  weak var delegate: ViewControllerOneDelegate?

  @objc private func donePressed() {
    delegate?.viewControllerOneDidTapDone(self)
  }

  @objc private func cancelPressed() {
    delegate?.viewControllerOneDidTapCancel(self)
  }
}
```

Lastly, somewhere in ViewControllerTwo, you need to set yourself as ViewControllerOne's delegate. This will likely be when creating ViewControllerOne:

```
class ViewControllerTwo: UIViewController {
  ...

  private func presentViewControllerOne() {
    let viewControllerOne = ViewControllerOne(nibName:nil, bundle: nil)
    viewControllerOne.delegate = self
    // Present or push viewControllerOne
  }

  ...
}
```